# Adjusting window scroll position in JavaScript to counteract element's resizing above

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, webkit

I'm trying to counteract an adjustment to the height of an element which is above the scroll offset by calculating the difference in height and then updating the current scroll position to account for it.

The problem is that there's no way that I can prevent a very quick flickering artefact. Whether I adjust the element's height and then the scroll position, or vice versa, I can't seem to prevent a quick visual jump.

Does anyone know how this could be overcome? I want these to operations to happen at the same time with no rendering in-between but I'm not sure if it's possible.

```
// Setup
...
var myElement = ...
var oldHeight = ...
var scrollOffset = window.scrollY;
var newHeight = 100;
var diff = newHeight - oldHeight;

// Determine if we need to counteract new size
var adjustScroll = (absoluteOffset(myElement) < scrollOffset);

// Adjust size
myElement.style.height = newHeight+'px';

// Adjust scroll to counteract the new height                    
if (adjustScroll) window.scrollTo(0, scrollOffset+diff);
```

I'm working with WebKit, specifically on iOS.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any way you could stop the flicker from happening because you don't say where on the page you're adding this element, but if you animated the change in height it would be less startling to the user than 2 quick position changes

Comment: The element who's height is adjusting is "above the scroll offset" as stated. The element always exists, but it's height changes out of sight and I'm trying to neutralise the change in page height & scroll position caused by this.

Comment: Yeah, its probably always going to be a little bit off, but like I said, if you animate it it will provide a better user experience. Then at least the user will know what happened and not have to stop and think about where they got placed on the page

Comment: Animating will look fairly bizarre. The page starts at specific scroll location, and should stay there. However, images above that scroll location will eventually load and that will push whatever is being viewed down and hence out of view. I'm trying to immediately detect the image loading and reset the scroll position once the image has been resized. Animating will just cause a smooth back and forth or shaking of the scroll position. I'm trying to remove all visual artefacts from it, if that's possible - hence the question!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be reviving an old post here, but i came across this looking for a solution to a similar problem to do with browser resizing.

Stackoverflow user [James Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847126/james-kyle) created this little jsfiddle using jQuery that attempts to maintain scroll position as best as possible when a page is resized

```
var html = $('html'),
    H = html.outerHeight(true),
    S = $(window).scrollTop(),
    P = S/H;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    S = $(window).scrollTop();
    P = S/H;
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    H = html.outerHeight(true);
    $(window).scrollTop(P*H);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/RmNap/

you could try using this same code and trigger a 'resize' event on the html when the image has loaded by using a jQuery library like [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

for webkit you can use CSS transitions/animations to smooth this but it's still sound like you are going the wrong way to begin with. I am sure that whatever is it you are trying to do can be solved purely with CSS (maybe with some very minimal Javaqscript). Post an example of you HTML + CSS + JS.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you understand the question. I'll reiterate what I've said in a comment above. The page starts at specific scroll location, and should stay there. However, images above that scroll location will eventually load and that will push whatever is being viewed down and out of view. I'm trying to immediately detect the image loading and reset the scroll position once the image has been resized.

Comment: why don't you load the images in hidden container or do an overflow hidden and when they are done (listening to onload) you can show them and shift the content with the scroll value. You can also do the content as position absolute and then change that to relative once the images are there. Kindo hacky but sounds like you will have some kind of a crazy solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) with timers to simulate multiple threads.
Or you could do it inside a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createDocumentFragment) beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a play with `scrollIntoView` and test out inserting document fragments into the DOM. Cheers!

Comment: @michael If that solves your problem remember to accept this answer later.